# php images upload does not work

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out why i am getting a bunch of errors when trying to upload multiple images

the input is `<input type='file' name='file[]' multiple>`

the check is:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file'])){
    if ($_FILES['file']['name'] != "") {
        $count = 0;       
        foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename) {
            $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');
            $img_name = $filename;
            $img_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $img_name)));
            $img_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$count];
            $count = $count + 1;
            if(in_array($img_extn, $allowed) === true){         
                $img_path = 'images/images/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $img_extn;
                move_uploaded_file($img_temp, $img_path);       

                $images = array(
                'images'    => $img_path,
                'post_id'       => $_POST['id']
                ); 
                add_images($images);    

            }else{
                $errors[] = ''.$filename.' - file type is not allowed. Only: ' . implode(', ', $allowed) . '';                                      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

only one image is being uploaded to the temp folder
and how can i connect the post_id to the database?

Comment: every place inside your loop where you are using `$_FILES['file']['name']` you should be using `$filename` instead

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `$filename` inside the `foreach` instead of `$_FILES['file']['name']`?

Comment: @Bamba if this answer was what helped you solve your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: it did but i still can't get the code to work properly. only one image is being uploaded to the temp folder for some reason

Comment: try to loop $_FILES['file'] instead of $_FILES['file']['name']

Comment: if i do that i get  Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string,

Comment: yes because then your $img_name = $filename becomes $img_name = $filename['name']

Comment: so it's better if you loop this way: 
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $file) {
// then use $file here
// like $filename = $file['name'];
// and so on..
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47568/discussion-between-bamba-and-ponciste)

Comment: you have to loop foreach($_FILES['file'] as $file), then use $file['name'] inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
$img_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

should be

```
$img_name = $filename;
```

since you are using for-each

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename) {
}
```

Comment: that seemed to fix the problem! that was fairly simple fix!

Comment: Yeah sometime simple things we tend to ignore but thats how we learn :)

Comment: True! how can my code is limiting it to 2 image paths to be inserted into the database? also, why won't it take the post id in?

Comment: Did not get u mean its only adding 2 images to DB ? Rest all are ignored ? if this this could be separate issue and needs the complete code before making any comment !!

Comment: that is the complete code! i mean there is the form too which is <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: use print_r($_FILES) before using the loop and see if all the files are getting posted !!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47565/discussion-between-bamba-and-abhik-chakraborty)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple images. it has to be $_FILES['file']['name'][0]

Use indexes to access it. Since I see that you haven't used indexes. explode() throws a warning because it's trying to break an array.

Comment: Or I'm guessing $filename[0] or any index will do too, with respect to your code.

Comment: what does the [0] do? right now only 2 image paths go through for some reason and only 2 images upload to the temp folder even if i select 4 images

Comment: Well, I meant you're going to have to pass indexes, not specifically 0. Basically, you want your code to loop through the number of photos that you select. So, in the case of your code, $_FILES['file']['name'][0] will refer to the first image selected, $_FILES['file']['name'][1] will refer to the second image selected, and so on.
So, you'll have to first count how many files exist in $_FILES['file']['name'], loop through each using an index and then let the rest of your code do its magic.

Comment: oh that's why i have $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$count]; $count = $count + 1;